# LWC split function doesn't return any value

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a custom label with comma seperated values: '17825,58963,01236'

```
import cli_message from '@salesforce/label/c.cli_message ';
        export default class sendMessage extends LightningElement {

         label = {cli_message};

        }
         connectedCallback() {
            //Object.values(this.label) returns the custom label values

          console.log(Object.values(this.label).split(',')) // returns nothing
        }
```

Comment: What does object.values(this.label) return?  What type?

Comment: It returns the custom label value.. 17825,58963,01236

Comment: Thats not a type, anyways, answered bellow, but yeah, split wont work if its an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `Object.values(this.label)` returns an array ( `["17825,58963,01236"]` ) while the **split()** method applies to a string.

What you can do is:

```
import cli_message from '@salesforce/label/c.cli_message ';

export default class sendMessage extends LightningElement {

   label = {cli_message};


   connectedCallback() {
      window.console.log("Object.values(this.label) >>", Object.values(this.label)) //Object.values(this.label) >> ["17825,58963,01236"]
      window.console.log("test", Object.values(this.label)[0].split(',')) //Array(3) ["17825", "58963", "01236"]
   }
}
```

Comment: you can also use this approach `window.console.log("array >> ", this.label.cli_message.split(","))`

Comment: I just realized that it was returning the value as array and not string Object.values(this.label).toString().split(',') worked for me.

Comment: glad that works. please can you accept my answer, there is a green button for that

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
var label = [12,13,234]; 
Object.keys(label).forEach(function(k, i) {
    console.log(label[k]);
});
```

Comment: label isn't an array, it is an object --> `label={cli_message: "17825,58963,01236"}`

Comment: also when the **Object.values()** method takes as parameter an array it returns an array not containing the elements but the indexes